# get totals of invoice collection: total incl. - total excl. - tax by types

Tags: sql, magento, join

**big picture**: I am working on generating .txt files for an accounting program.
I have to sum up

- total Tax Included
- total Tax Excluded
- total of Taxes by type

**in detail**: I have a collection of invoices:

```
    private function _getInvoiceCollectionPerStore($storeId)
    {
        $invoices = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection')
                ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.store_id', $storeId);
        //orde increment id
        $invoices->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                'order_increment_id',
                'order.increment_id',
                'main_table.order_id'
        );
        //customer id
        $invoices->getSelect()->join(
                array('order' => 'sales_flat_order'),
                'main_table.order_id = order.entity_id',
                array('order.customer_id'));

        return $invoices;
    }
```

with that collection I can calculate total tax included and total tax excluded.

```
        $invoices->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                'order_total',
                'SUM({{main_table.grand_total}})',
                'main_table.grand_total'
        );
        $invoices->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                'tax_total',
                'SUM({{main_table.tax_amount}})',
                'main_table.tax_amount'
        );
```

Now I want to calculate the sum of the different taxes of thoses invoices/orders.
For that, I have the table `sales_order_tax` where I have the different taxes for each order:

```
| tax_id | order_id | code | percent | amount |
|    1   |     1    |  18  | 18.0000 | 25.0100|
|    2   |     1    |   8  |  8.0000 |  1.1100|
|    3   |     2    |  18  | 18.0000 |  3.2000|
|    4   |     2    |   4  |  4.0000 |  0.6500|
```

(I have simplified the table, as this are the only fields relevant here).
As you see with my dummy data, I have 2 orders (ids 1 and 2) with 3 types of tax (4, 8 and 18).
The result I want is:

```
18 = 28.21 ( => 25.01+3.2)
 8 = 1.11
 4 = 0.65
```

And, finally, my question is: can I get this result with join and groups statements? Or do I have to loop through the collection to sum it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you question correctly, this will give this SQL statment will give you the total amount per tax code

```
Select code, SUM(amount) 
    from sales_order_tax 
group by code
```